# bit-wise for-each function

Tags: c, foreach, bit-manipulation, bit

I have a long list of single bits uint32 numbers. Sometimes they are || together to form a new number. For each set bit in this new number, I need to perform a certain operation. So basictly I'm writing a loop to iterat through each bit of the number.

I know that I can do this easily with a while loop. But since I need to this same thing in many parts of hte code. I figure I can make a function for it (just like the `json_object_foreach()` function).

For the function arguments, I'm parsing in the original number, the starting bit's position (assuming starting from the 0th bit, but if it doesn't make sense, I can also starting from 1), and what the numerical value this bit is.

I have the following so far. The code does compile. However the code is not iterating from 0-31. I'm pretty sure the `get_next_bit_position` function is not right bit I don't know how to fix it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint32_t get_value_of_kth_bit(uint32_t original_number, int bit_position)
{
    int result = 0;
    // if the bit_position is set to 1
    printf("original_number is: %u\n", original_number);
    printf("bit_position is: %d\n", bit_position);
    if (original_number & (1 << (bit_position))){
        // if the bit_position is set to 1
        // calculate the numerical value
        if(bit_position == 0){
            result = 1;
        }
        while (bit_position!=0){
            result*=2;
            --bit_position;
        }
        printf("result: %d\n", result);
        return result;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

uint32_t get_next_bit_position(uint32_t bit_position)
{
    printf("bit_position input is : %u\n", bit_position);
    if(bit_position < 32){
        bit_position++;
    }
    printf("new bit_position is : %u\n", bit_position);
    return bit_position;
}

#define foreach_bit(original_number, bit_position, current_bit_value) \
    for(current_bit = 0; \
       current_bit_value = get_value_of_kth_bit(original_number, bit_position); \
       current_bit = get_next_bit_position(current_bit))

#define CLASS_A    0x00000001  // 0001
#define CLASS_B    0x00000002
#define CLASS_C    0x00000010  // 1010
#define CLASS_D    0x00000400
//...
// the list goes on 

int main(){

    uint32_t num = CLASS_A | CLASS_C; // 1011

    uint32_t current_bit = 0;
    uint32_t current_bit_value = 0;


    foreach_bit(num, current_bit, current_bit_value){
        printf("Entered function\n");

        if(current_bit_value = CLASS_A){
            printf("Found class_a bit\n");
            // do something else
        } 
        else if (current_bit_value = CLASS_B){
            printf("Found class_b bit\n");
            // do something else
        } 
        else if (current_bit_value = CLASS_D) {
            printf("Found class_c bit\n");
            // do something else
        }
    }
}
```

The code outputs the following, which it's weird. Since I think the function should enter the `foreach_bit` function before running `get_value_of_kth_bit`

```
original_number is: 17
bit_position is: 0
result: 1
Entered function
Found class_a bit
bit_position input is : 0
new bit_position is : 1
original_number is: 17
bit_position is: 1
```

Update about requirements:

1. I know a list of total 32 1-bit uint32 numbers. Let call it Class List

```
#define CLASS_A    0x00000001  // 0001
#define CLASS_B    0x00000002
#define CLASS_C    0x00000004  // 0100
#deifne CLASS_D    0x00000008
#define CLASS_E    0x00000010
#define CLASS_F    0x00000020
....
```

2. I will be given one random uint32 number, and I need to see how many and which Class List this random number(original_number) contain.
3. I have a herlper function which takes the Class List number (uint32) and do something. For example `get_class_name_str(uint32 class_number)`

For example, the original_number is 5 (binary: 0101).
I check the first bit (right most) which is 1 (0001). And 0001 is the value for CLASS_A. So I see that the CLASS_A is in this original_number, and I can parse it to the helper funciton to do somethine.
Then, the second bit it set to 0, which means CLASS_B is not in this original_number.
The third bit is 1, which means CLASS_C is a part of original_number.

I can do this in a while loop, to check each bits. However, I would like this to be a funcytion itself since it's used in mutiple places.

Comment: In `if(current_bit_value = CLASS_A)` the assignment `=` is not the comparison `==`. (Aside: we don't `||` bits together, we `|` them.)

Comment: Please don't make "live updates" to mistakes in the code.

Comment: Sorry about that. I changed the "II" from diescription to "|". And cahnged the assignment ```=``` to ```==``` in the ```foreach_bit()``` in the main function

Comment: Did it fix the code on your own machine?

Comment: Unfortunatly no, the output remain the same

Comment: Are you sure the exit condition on your for loop (from the macro) is correct? It seems to be trying to exit on the first 0 bit.

Comment: I'm compiling with ```gcc -o test test.c``` if that matters

Comment: @EdmCoff I don't think it's right. It's my first time attempting to write macro function. I'm still looking at the documentation at the meantime

Comment: My point is that a loop in the format `for ( ... ; a = b; ... )` is going to exit when b is 0. In your case, it will exit when `get_value_of_kth_bit(original_number, bit_position)` evaluates to 0. I don't think that's what you're expecting.

Comment: It seems a very long-winded contrivance. The bit in position `k` is either `(num >> k) & 1` or `num & (1u << k)` depending on where you want the bit value to be. It's one line of code.

Comment: Isn't this off-by-one? `if(bit_position < 32) { bit_position++; }`

Comment: @WeatherVane does the left shift and rigth shit matter inthis case? I chose right shift becasue it's easier to calculate the exponent. 

If ```0``` is the first bit, I think the last bit should be ```31``` adding up to total 32 bits

Comment: The right-shift version isolates the required bit in b0, and the left-shift version isolates the required bit in-place. Which one you use depends on the use case. My other point is that there isn't a bit position 32 in a 32-bit variable, they are 0 to 31.

Comment: Soo just `for (uint32_t i = 0, v = 1; (v <<= 1, i < 32); ++i) printf("%x\n", v);`? Could you post the interface in the form: what is the input and what should happen for that input? `For each set bit in this new number, I need to perform a certain operation` So a input like `0x89` should produce a sequence of three numbers `0x80` `0x8` `0x1`? Input like `0x14` should produce a sequence of two numbers `0x10` `0x4`?

Comment: @KamilCuk requirement updated in hte original post

Comment: But why write a loop at all? Why not just check the bits? Just `if (num & CLASS_A){} if (num & CLASS_B) {}`? There is little point in iterating over bits if you are checking the bits over a set of predefined values - just check the values against the input....

Comment: @KamilCuk I agree that performance-wise speaking, directly checking the bits is faster. Personally, I think the for loop looks a bit more elegant.  Thank you for going through the trouble and creating the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So basictly I'm writing a loop to iterat through each bit of the number.

I think you are overcomplicating it. Just literally iterate over the bits, and exclude bits that are not set:

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < 32; ++i) {
   uint32_t bit = 1u << i;
   if (!(num & bit)) continue;
   // use bit
}
```

Which we can squeeze in that macro:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define foreach_bit(BIT, ITER, NUM) \
    for (uint32_t BIT, ITER = 0; ITER < 32 && (BIT = 1u << ITER, 1); ++ITER) \
       if (!(NUM & BIT)) \
           continue; \
       else

int main() {
    uint32_t val = 0b1011;
    foreach_bit(i, _in, val) {
        printf("%x\n", i);
    }
}
```

The code snippets outputs:

```
1
2
8
```

Then we could even remove the need for bit position by checking if the mask will be zero when shifted - it will only be, when the last bit is taken/ The following looks quite nice, and I think I would prefer it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define foreach_bit(BIT, NUM) \
    for (uint32_t BIT = 1; BIT << 1; BIT <<= 1) \
       if (!(NUM & BIT)) \
           continue; \
       else

int main() {
    uint32_t val = 0b1011;
    foreach_bit(i, val) {
        printf("%x\n", i);
    }
}
```

Another idea, you do not need really "bit position" - you could remove the visited bits from the input instead, calculating the mask from the first bit set in the input:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <strings.h>

#define foreach_bit(IDX, STATE, VAL) \
    for (uint32_t STATE = VAL, IDX; \
        STATE ? (IDX = 1 << (ffsl((long)STATE) - 1)) : 0; \
        STATE &= ~IDX)

int main(){
    uint32_t num = 0b1011;
    foreach_bit(i, _in, num) {
        printf("%x\n", i);
    }
}
```

In your code, you check only once for `if (original_number & (1 << (bit_position))){` - you have to check for that inside `while (bit_position!=0){` loop and start checking from the bit last visited.

---

Anyway, there is very little point in writing any loop in the presented code. Just check the bits:

```
int main(){
        uint32_t num = CLASS_A | CLASS_C
        if (num & CLASS_A){
            printf("Found class_a bit\n");
            // do something else
        } 
        else if (num & CLASS_B){
            printf("Found class_b bit\n");
            // do something else
        } 
        else if (num & CLASS_D) {
            printf("Found class_c bit\n");
            // do something else
        }
}
```